# Flash Builder 4 Debugger Variables Not Updating

Tags: flash, debugging, builder

Damndest thing. Every once in a while, I'll make a change to some part of my Flash application, while working in Flash Builder 4, and when I click Debug Play, it starts running with the old code and the old variables, even though the code I'm looking at in the code window is the new, changed code. I can still advance step by step, but the advances don't align with the new code. They seem to be aligning with the old, not visible code. I can eliminate variables entirely, save, build clean, and when I run, it still shows the old variables in the Variables window. As I can not find any mention of this on the Internet, I logically conclude that this is some ancient curse directed solely at me.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens clear your browser's cache.  Works every time for me.  Frustrating, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same with Run Mode? If so FB isnt building your app.

As Mentioned here...
[clean project in flash builder on debug launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976111/clean-project-in-flash-builder-on-debug-launch)

you can try Build Automatically/Manually

From Adobe Docs, if you have gone through this, please ignore.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7feb.html#WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e64

As a final try - remove your bin-debug folder and build the project.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated.

Unfortunately, none of that seems to work.

Build Clean doesn't help. Build All doesn't help. I can't find a folder called "bin-debug" on my machine or in the Package Explorer. I have been Building Automatically. Not sure what Run Mode means ("non-debug"?)

Is there a place on the net where I can pay to get specific support on this? 

Thank you.

This is still killing me. I have hit a total wall. No amount of restarting seems to get the debugger to work against new code. Never had this problem until recently. Now I can make zero progress.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and fixed it.

There is a config screw up somewhere

1. Copy/save your main src with all your code directory I used git but
   I would imagine you could just copy it locally.
2. Delete the project entirely
3. Make a new directory with the same project name in the same
   location using your OS or command line, do not do this in Flash
   Builder.
4. Copy your saved src directory into this directory.
5. In flash builder create a new project, but instead of using the default folder as the
   file location select your new directory.
6. You should now have a fresh project with the same code as the old one but without the
   config screw up.